# Could not find builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.0)

Tags: java, android, gradle, maven-2, android-studio-3.1

I wanted to Setting up android studio, i have installed the latest version(3.1.0) of it and i downloaded and installed the latest version of gradle(4.6) and created a new object. but gradle project sync failed. and shown up the error :

> Could not find builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.0).
>   Searched in the following locations:
>       https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.1.0/builder-3.1.0.jar

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvaqR.png)

I Couldn't find such problem with the others.

1. is it related to android sdk or gradle version?
2. is there any solution to download it manually and place it in the
   location??if it's possible , where is the location ,that i can put the
   builder-3.1.0.jar file.

Comment: paste your error also and your app gradle too

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Go to File>Setting>Build,Execution,Deployment>Gradle>Android Studio>>
and
Check mark this:: Enable Embedded repository
and Click Ok.
Then,
Rebuild the Project.

or

go to Terminal and type "gradlew cleanBuildCache" to clear the cache. The cache is in USERNAME.ANDROID\BUILD CACHE Directory.

And Rebuild.

Comment: sorry cause late answer i uninstalled the android studio & installed the 3.1.1 version & and i have a new error : Could not connect to server [fc3d9512-540e-47b4-9cb0-8d3b0c134fbe port:5736, addresses:[/127.0.0.1]]. Tried addresses: [/127.0.0.1].

Comment: it's not related to conection because i can update sdk from sdk manager but when i want to sync gradle this message was displayed

Comment: i tried your solution. and it works. thank you so much

Comment: where is this section in AS 4.1.1?

Answer (score 6):

Accepted answer did not work for me, so I changed the class path line in gradle (`project : project name`) and issue is gone.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
```

Comment: This helped thanks. It seems like there is a problem with the new version!

Answer (score 6):

Try **deleting ~/.gradle** folder and **building** the project again. Gradle will download that.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried all of the suggestions and none of them worked! 
if you are facing the same issue i suggest you to do what solved my problem , i have found out the problem may caused because:

> most likely at one time this dependency version was available, and so it’s now available on your Mac/PC in the filesystem (cache), and Gradle won’t try to download it (as it’s already downloaded). But then the version was removed / is no longer available, so it will no longer work on any new Mac/PC (as the dependency version can’t be downloaded).

hopefully if you have a backup before this problem happen these steps might help you to fix this issue

**1) Backup or push the file you have changed to git (I suggest just your code files not anything related to gradles or android files)**

**2) delete C:\Users\ (your User)\ .gradle\caches**

**3) Do a clean git clone of the repository, into a new directory**

**4) Open new copy of your project with Android Studio and let Android studio sync gradles again**

Answer (score 1):

Check the version of Android Studio you are using...i was Android Studio 3.1 when it gave me the problem....i downgraded my Android Studio version to 3.0.1 and the problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I battled with the same problem for a very long time. But I was able to resolve it. You can try this:
Go **FIle > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment> Build Tools > Gradle** then check the option **Offline Work** . You will notice that it points to a local gradle directory on your computer i.e C:Users/User_name/.gradle. Click **Apply** then **OK**. Run your project again, it should work.
Below is a screenshot:[Screenshot of the Fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSRDN.png)

Answer (score 0):

go to SDK manager and download other SDK platform